# End whileloop using python shell

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a stopwatch that my peers have challenged me to build, but I want it to be able to stop the timer when I type in a certain key into the python shell.

```
import time

timer = 0
timeTrueFalse = True

startTimer = input("Type start if you want to start!")

if (startTimer == "start"):
    while timeTrueFalse:
            timer = (timer + 1)
            print (timer)
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: *Any* key or a *specific* key?  Pressing Control+C raises a `KeyboardInterrupt`, which you can catch. Also, you don't need the parenthesis in the `if` statement. `if startTimer == "start":` will work fine ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Good thinking with Ctrl+C.  I didn't think of that.

Comment: Read this. There are a couple of links in there as well that might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400806/stopwatch-in-python-count-until-you-press-space

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamps

```
import time

while not str(raw_input("write start: ")) == "start" :
    pass

tstamp=time.time()

while not str(raw_input("write stop: ")) == "stop" :
    pass    

delta=time.time()-tstamp

#delta has the time in seconds.
```

Comment: "but I want it to be able to stop the timer when I type in a certain key into the python shell"

Comment: So you put the exit validation before the delta line. You don't need sleep if you can use the system timer